# Headless Eclipse hangs on JFrame

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, jframe, equinox

I'm working on a headless eclipse application. The application itself works nicely (both if run from eclipse or exported as product). My problems comes when I try to use swing to render a `JFrame`, the applications just hangs on the creation of the frame, without triggering any error. Is this intended and I'm trying to do something impossible or did I miss something?

Simple snippet:

```
package headless;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

import org.eclipse.equinox.app.IApplication;
import org.eclipse.equinox.app.IApplicationContext;

/**
 * This class controls all aspects of the application's execution
 */
public class Application implements IApplication {

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.eclipse.equinox.app.IApplication#start(org.eclipse.equinox.app.IApplicationContext)
     */
    @Override
    public Object start(final IApplicationContext context) throws Exception {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
        return IApplication.EXIT_OK;
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.eclipse.equinox.app.IApplication#stop()
     */
    @Override
    public void stop() {
        // nothing to do
    }
}
```

Note: the application doesn't just terminate, it gets stuck  on the creation of the frame and never reaches the return statement.

Comment: If the machine is headless, it won't be able to display a `JFrame` (note upper and lower case letters).

Comment: I see. I guess there's no way to have a UI in that case?

Comment: Certainly no way to have a GUI.  A headless device might not even have a **monitor.**

Comment: I see, I guess I didn't understand it properly: I though it would just be separated from the standard GUI, not that it woudl have been unable to have one at all. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @AndrewThompson: As suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13984381/230513), I've used VNC on a headless server as a workaround.

Comment: Possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5679943/230513).